# Failed to inflate imageview holoeverywhere

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

Hello i have a problem inflate my layout when i export my app.

I got this error message when exporting my app:

```
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191): Failed to inflate
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #290: Error inflating class org.holoeverywhere.widget.ImageView
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:450)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:731)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:734)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:734)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:734)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:488)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.requestDecorView(_HoloActivity.java:580)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.setContentView(_HoloActivity.java:604)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at com.example.workoutlog.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:132)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.holoeverywhere.widget.ImageView" on path: /mnt/asec/com.tigo-1/pkg.apk
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater._createView(LayoutInflater.java:330)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:590)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:444)
10-10 13:25:25.559: E/ActivityThread(28191):    ... 23 more
10-10 13:25:25.579: D/AndroidRuntime(28191): Shutting down VM
10-10 13:25:25.579: W/dalvikvm(28191): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f86930)
10-10 13:25:25.579: W/GAV2(28191): Thread[main,5,main]: dispatch call queued.  Need to call GAServiceManager.getInstance().initialize().
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tigo/com.example.workoutlog.HomePage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #290: Error inflating class org.holoeverywhere.widget.ImageView
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #290: Error inflating class org.holoeverywhere.widget.ImageView
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:450)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:731)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:734)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:734)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:734)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:488)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.requestDecorView(_HoloActivity.java:580)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.setContentView(_HoloActivity.java:604)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at com.example.workoutlog.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:132)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    ... 11 more
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.holoeverywhere.widget.ImageView" on path: /mnt/asec/com.tigo-1/pkg.apk
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater._createView(LayoutInflater.java:330)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:590)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:444)
10-10 13:25:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    ... 23 more
10-10 13:25:25.609: D/dalvikvm(28191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1696K, 25% free 5716K/7588K, paused 10ms+18ms, total 71ms
10-10 13:25:28.983: W/GAV2(28191): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
```

The message do not appear when running the app from eclipse.
My proguard is off.
Its very strange because when running from eclipse everything is good.

The line the logcat points at its:

```
<android.widget.ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workoutWall2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/workout_wall" />
```

Thank for helping!

This the my XML its referring to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/homePageLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tempTab"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/homePageTab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45sp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:text="Home page"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/homeLine"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5sp"
                android:background="@color/Blue"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/extraTab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45sp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:text="Extra tools"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/extraLine"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5sp"
                android:background="@color/Black"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tempTab"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/blockHelper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25sp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView06"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/setToday"
                android:layout_below="@+id/setToday"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="today log"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/calendarPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView04"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView06"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/dietHomePage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/diet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/calendarPage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/calendarPage"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="calendar"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView06"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dietHomePage"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dietHomePage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dietHomePage"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="diet"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/liveWorkout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/setWorkOutProgram"
                android:layout_below="@+id/setWorkOutProgram"
                android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/stopwatch" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/statistics"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/liveWorkout"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/line_chart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/liveWorkout"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/liveWorkout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/liveWorkout"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="live"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/statistics"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/statistics"
                android:layout_below="@+id/statistics"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="statistics"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/setWorkOutProgram"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/setWorkOutProgram"
                android:layout_below="@+id/setWorkOutProgram"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="program"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/goRoutines"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/goRoutines"
                android:layout_below="@+id/goRoutines"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="routine"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dietWall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:clickable="true" >

                <android.widget.ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dietWall2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/diet_wall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dietWall2"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dietWall2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/dietWall2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="diet wall"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/setToday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/liveWorkout"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar_today" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/goRoutines"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/workoutWall"
                android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/routine" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/setWorkOutProgram"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dietWall"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/program" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/personalDetails"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/personalDetails"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/personalDetails"
                android:layout_below="@+id/personalDetails"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="details"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/workoutWall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/personalDetails"
                android:background="@drawable/home_page_icon"
                android:clickable="true" >

                <android.widget.ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workoutWall2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/workout_wall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workoutWall2"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/workoutWall2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workoutWall2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="workout wall"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingProgress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/rotate_progress"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please check your minimum apk version

Comment: Its SDK8 what should i learn from it? ImageView its since API 1

Comment: But what about holoeverywhere

Comment: It looks like the error details a different `ImageView` class (from `org.holoeverywhere.widget.ImageView`) as opposed to `android.widget.ImageView`.  Could you clarify if this is the case?  If you are in fact using the `ImageView` class from the `holoeverywhere` package, consider Ameer's recommendations above.

Comment: I dont understand his solution.
Imageview and holoeveywhere are supported on API 8.